# Complex issue with MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, sql

OK, so I'm facing this extremely complicated issue and since I'm not a guru with MySQL I'd definitely need your input on that.

Let's say we've got a database, created using the code below (I'm pasting the creation code - of just the absolutely-necessary tables -  to avoid pasting all the tables) :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Jeweller`.`Orders`;
CREATE TABLE `Jeweller`.`Orders` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Jeweller`.`Product_categories`;
CREATE TABLE `Jeweller`.`Product_categories` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Jeweller`.`Product_orders`;
CREATE TABLE `Jeweller`.`Product_orders` (
  `order_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11),
  `value` float,
  FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `Jeweller`.`Orders`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `Jeweller`.`Products`(`id`),
  CHECK (`quantity`>0),
  CHECK (`value`>0)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Jeweller`.`Product_returns`;
CREATE TABLE `Jeweller`.`Product_returns` (
  `sale_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11),
  `value` float,
  FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `Jeweller`.`Sales`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `Jeweller`.`Products`(`id`),
  CHECK (`quantity`>0),
  CHECK (`value`>0)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Jeweller`.`Product_sales`;
CREATE TABLE `Jeweller`.`Product_sales` (
  `sale_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11),
  `value` float,
  FOREIGN KEY (`sale_id`) REFERENCES `Jeweller`.`Sales`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `Jeweller`.`Products`(`id`),
  CHECK (`quantity`>0),
  CHECK (`value`>0)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Jeweller`.`Products`;
CREATE TABLE `Jeweller`.`Products` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `seller_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`product_category_id`) REFERENCES `Jeweller`.`Product_categories`(`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`seller_id`) REFERENCES `Jeweller`.`Sellers`(`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Jeweller`.`Sales`;
CREATE TABLE `Jeweller`.`Sales` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now, given that we define **Profit** as :

- `Sales - Returns - Orders`

**How would you go about a query to fetch :**

Profit by month AND product_category, only for the year 2013.

---

For testing purposes, here's the  full [DB Creation code](http://pastebin.com/2RxPJpGR) as well as the [DB Population code](http://pastebin.com/WGaKdwfP) (with some demo data). ([SQLFiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6380e))

---

**P.S.**

- The actual code is kinda different (the above is just an example - though a 100% loyal one)
- After several attempts I've managed to just filter 2013 sales/orders/etc... I've even managed to get Profit by product (though it took some endless `join`s, `left outer join`s, etc... lol)... However this looks much more complicated. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not use FLOAT for this. These are (almost certainly) decimals, not floating point numbers.

Comment: @Strawberry Well I did that - for the purposes of the example - to represent values (prices) that may even be like "200.30" rather than integers...

Comment: Yes. Those are decimals. Oh and foreign key constraints have no meaning in MyISAM, so let's ignore those for now...

Comment: @Strawberry Really?? I've always used them - didn't know they were being ignored... :S

Comment: It may not matter, but are sales in any way related to orders?

Comment: Combine some of your tables, if they have the same structure you can very likely combine them, Have a flag or an enum to show differences. your returns, orders and sales could be 1 table.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon they should still be decimal i.e. DECIMAL(10,2).  The amount of issues I've had over the years due to someone using FLOAT as a shortcut are just NOT worth the hassle, always use DECIMAL :)  Anyway will take a look through your post now instead of the comments in case I can help !  Have added in an SQLFiddle link with your data for others to use

Comment: Does the calculation need to multiply 'value' by 'quantity'?

Comment: "I've even managed to get Profit by product": add a `GROUP BY (MONTH(date), product_category)` at the end of your query, and use `SELECT SUM(profit) AS total_profit, date AS month, product_category` as a SELECT clause, and there you are.

Comment: adding an sqlfiddle.com with some test data would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approximation of your schema...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;
CREATE TABLE orders 
( order_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment
, date date DEFAULT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (order_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO orders VALUES
(NULL,'2013-01-01'),
(NULL,'2013-01-01'),
(NULL,'2013-02-02'),
(NULL,'2013-02-03'),
(NULL,'2013-03-05'),
(NULL,'2013-06-07');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_orders;
CREATE TABLE product_orders 
( order_id int unsigned NOT NULL
, product_id int unsigned NOT NULL
, quantity int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
, value DECIMAL(5,2)
, PRIMARY KEY(order_id,product_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO product_orders VALUES
(1,101,1,100),
(1,102,1,50),
(2,101,2,200),
(3,101,1,100),
(4,102,2,100),
(4,103,3,150),
(5,104,1,300),
(6,102,1,50),
(6,103,2,100),
(6,104,1,300);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_returns;
CREATE TABLE product_returns 
( sale_id int unsigned NOT NULL
, product_id int NOT NULL
, date date DEFAULT NULL
, quantity int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
, value DECIMAL(5,2)
, PRIMARY KEY(sale_id,product_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO product_returns VALUES
(21,101,'2013-01-04',2,200),
(22,102,'2013-03-06',1,50),
(22,103,'2013-05-08',1,50),
(23,104,'2013-06-09',1,300);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_sales;
CREATE TABLE product_sales 
( sale_id int unsigned NOT NULL
, product_id int NOT NULL
, quantity int NOT NULL
, value DECIMAL(5,2)
, PRIMARY KEY(sale_id,product_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO product_sales VALUES
(20,101,1,100),
(20,102,1,50),
(21,101,3,300),
(22,101,1,100),
(22,102,2,100),
(22,103,1,50),
(23,103,2,100),
(23,104,2,600);


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products;
CREATE TABLE products 
( product_id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
, product_category_id int NOT NULL
, name varchar(100) NOT NULL
, description text NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO products VALUES
(101,1,'donuts','Mmm, donuts'),
(102,2,'buzz Cola','Mmm, donuts'),
(103,2,'duff beer','Can\'t get enough'),
(104,1,'Krusty-O\'s','Yum, yum');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sales;
CREATE TABLE sales
( sale_id int NOT NULL
, date date DEFAULT NULL
, PRIMARY KEY (sale_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO sales VALUES
(20,'2013-01-12'),
(21,'2013-02-15'),
(22,'2013-03-17'),
(23,'2013-05-18');
```

...and a possible query...

```
SELECT p.product_category_id
     , MONTH(date) month
     , SUM(value) profit
  FROM 
     ( SELECT product_id,value, date 
         FROM product_sales ps
         JOIN sales s
           ON s.sale_id = ps.sale_id
        UNION ALL
       SELECT product_id,value*-1,date FROM product_returns
        UNION ALL
       SELECT product_id,value*-1,date
         FROM product_orders po
         JOIN orders o
           ON o.order_id = po.order_id
     ) x
  JOIN products p
    ON p.product_id = x.product_id
 WHERE YEAR(date) = 2013
 GROUP
    BY p.product_category_id
     , MONTH(date);

+---------------------+-------+---------+
| product_category_id | month | profit  |
+---------------------+-------+---------+
|                   1 |     1 | -400.00 |
|                   1 |     2 |  200.00 |
|                   1 |     3 | -200.00 |
|                   1 |     5 |  600.00 |
|                   1 |     6 | -600.00 |
|                   2 |     1 |    0.00 |
|                   2 |     2 | -250.00 |
|                   2 |     3 |  100.00 |
|                   2 |     5 |   50.00 |
|                   2 |     6 | -150.00 |
+---------------------+-------+---------+
```

...and an sqlfiddle of same :http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22a1d/1

Comment: The use of `WHERE YEAR(date) = 2013` instead of matching on a date range is less efficient in the long run.  Likewise you could use the computed `MONTH(date) month` column in the GROUP instead of re-applying `MONTH()`.  Finally your version of the subquery, while only requiring the date specified once will select all data for all date periods leading to it becoming progressively slower

Comment: While true, if the OP had a dataset of the size you're envisaging for the problem to become apparent, I doubt they'd be asking us for help!

Comment: After helping with some other datasets I'd rather not make that assumption, as I don't want to be the one cleaning this up when the dataset grows too big to handle due to inefficient queries!

Comment: Immensely helpful! You can't imagine how much you've helped me... Thanks, buddy! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In simplest terms, if restructuring is undesirable, then I would do a simple query to determine the value of orders, returns, and sales seperately and then join those together.  This could be done using UNION and subqueries as in the following example : [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/523685/5)

I've also taken the liberty of swapping the FLOATs for DECIMALs.  There is probably room for improvement on indexes and the like but this should put you on a good track for determining the sums.  If you look at the subquery you'll see that ORDER and RETURN selects are selecting a negative value as per your requirement.

One potential pitfall is that any records for which the record from Product has been deleted would not be included.  This could be avoided by changing the `Product` joins into LEFT JOINs and handling the NULL value for product_category_id appropriately.  Decided to add this into the latest example, though if the rows from `Product` are **NEVER** deleted, then INNER JOIN will suffice

```
SELECT

  d.thisMonth,
  d.product_category_id,
  SUM(d.sumValue)

FROM (

  (
    -- Get the order value

    SELECT

      'order' AS valueType,
      MONTH(o.date) AS thisMonth,
      p.product_category_id,
      SUM(-po.value * po.quantity) AS sumValue

    FROM Orders o

    INNER JOIN Product_orders po
    ON po.order_id = o.id

    LEFT JOIN Products p
    ON p.id = po.product_id

    WHERE o.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'

    GROUP BY
        thisMonth,
        product_category_id

  ) UNION ALL (

    -- Get the sales value

    SELECT

      'sale' AS valueType,
      MONTH(s.date) AS thisMonth,
      p.product_category_id,
      SUM(ps.value * ps.quantity) AS sumValue

    FROM Sales s

    INNER JOIN Product_sales ps
    ON ps.sale_id = s.id

    INNER JOIN Products p
    ON p.id = ps.product_id


    WHERE s.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'

    GROUP BY
        thisMonth,
        product_category_id

  ) UNION ALL (

    -- Get the return value

    SELECT

      'return' AS valueType,
      p.product_category_id,
      MONTH(pr.date) AS thisMonth,
      SUM(-pr.value * pr.quantity) AS sumValue

    FROM Product_returns pr

    INNER JOIN Products p
    ON p.id = pr.product_id

    WHERE pr.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'

    GROUP BY
        thisMonth,
        product_category_id

  )
) d
GROUP BY 
  d.thisMonth,
  d.product_category_id;
```